# Adding a user to a group in django

Tags: python, django

How would I add a user to a group in django by the group's name?

I can do this:

```
user.groups.add(1) # add by id
```

How would I do something like this:

```
user.groups.add(name='groupname') # add by name
```

Comment: Is this solution version sensitive? When I tried this is django 1.8, I got "unexpected keyword: name"

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Find the group using Group model with the name of the group, then add the user to the user_set

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
my_group = Group.objects.get(name='my_group_name') 
my_group.user_set.add(your_user)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems silly that some of the most basic things are either missing or hard to find in the django docs

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/          There are similar examples in section 'Playing with the API'

Comment: The tutorial is pretty useful, What I meant was that I would expect to see in a section of the docs under auth for programmatically creating groups. instead all there is is a weak paragraph: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#groups I guess it helps to keep in mind that the auth models are just regular models, and the standard model reference applies.

Comment: where is `user_set` in Django doc? I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: @MinhThai the default value for a reverse relation field is `<content_type>_set` when `related_name` is not set on the field.

Comment: Does anyone know how to the same to a specific database?

Answer (score 134):

Here's how to do this in modern versions of Django (tested in Django 1.7):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
group = Group.objects.get(name='groupname')
user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: you can also do `Group.objects.get_by_natural_key('groupname')`, but it doesn't make it shorted :D

Comment: @enchance Wherever you need to do so. Probably within the code for a View that's doing Group assignments.

Answer (score 11):

coredumperror is right but I have found one thing I need to share that one

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

# get_or_create return error due to 
new_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name = 'groupName')
print(type(new_group))       # return tuple

new_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name = 'groupName')
user.groups.add(new_group)   # new_group as tuple and it return error

# get() didn't return error due to 
new_group = Group.objects.get(name = 'groupName')
print(type(new_group))       # return <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>

user = User.objects.get(username = 'username')
user.groups.add(new_group)   # new_group as object and user is added
```

Comment: this is because get_or_create returns a tuple: (object, created).  ```new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name = 'groupName')```   would work

Comment: oh that's too great

Comment: Remember to import also `User` since you call the object. Basically: `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User`

Answer (score 4):

You can assign multiple groups to a user using the `set` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

users = Group.objects.get(name="user")
managers = Group.objects.get(name="manager")
user.groups.set([users, managers])
```