# django populate db with some data when new user is created

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I populate the following tables with some default / initial data, every-time new user is created ? I know about this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/, but this works only when I create models. Here I want to insert some default entries when new user is created.

Additionally, when I create a new user how can I add him to a given group with a static group id automatically ?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Feed(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/login")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm1()
    return render(request, "registration/signup.html", {
        'form': form,

    })
```

forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm1(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

Many thanks!

Comment: searching google and this forum is what I did so far but I can't figure it out. I'm thinking I would have to add it somewhere in the UserCreationForm1 ?

Comment: but each time a user is created, initial data will be stored for him/her if you do default https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default.I am not sure if that is what you want though. About saving the user to a group, you can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288661/adding-a-user-to-a-group-in-django/6288863#6288863, maybe extend the user model and add this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is Django's signals framework.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from my_app import Category, Feed

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def init_new_user(instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    # raw is set when model is created from loaddata.
    if created and not raw:
        instance.groups.add(
            Group.objects.get(name='new-user-group'))

        Category.objects.create(
            name="Default", user=instance)

        Feed.objects.create(
            user = instance,
            name = "%s's Feed" % instance.first_name,
            ....
        )
```

REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signals/

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways you can handle populating additional models with data when creating a new user. This first one that comes to mind is a `post_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signals/):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from your_app.models import Category, Feed

@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Coupon)
def add_user_data(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.get('instance')

    try:
        category, category_created = Category.objects.get_or_create(user=user,
            defaults={'name': 'Some Value', 'user': user})

        try:
            feed, feed_Created = Feed.objects.get_or_create(user=user,
                category=category, defaults={'url': 'some-url',
                    'name': 'some-name', 'description': 'some-desc',
                    'category': category, 'user': user})
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            pass
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        pass
```

This code would execute any time an instance of `User` is saved, but only create the additional records if they don't already exist for that user.

Another way would be to override the `save()` method on a form for the User. If you also need this functionality in Django admin, you would need to un-register the built-in UserAdmin and register your own UserAdmin class to leverage the custom form.