# Add users to groups in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using the Group module in Django.

I've created views `GroupCreateView` and `GroupUpdateView` in which I can update permissions and group name, but I also want to add users to the groups.

Right now I have to update each user object and set to which groups it belongs. I want to do it the other way around where I create groups and add users to this group.

How is this obtained? I guess it's something like `group.user_set.add(user)`

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288661/adding-a-user-to-a-group-in-django

Comment: But how can I add it to the CreateView and UpdateView? Do I have to create a custom ModelForm?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to add a newly created user to an **existing** group **automatically**. Correct me if I am wrong since this is not stated in your question.

Here is what I have in **views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['username'] #only expose the username field for the sake of simplicity add more fields as you need

    #this one is called when a user has been created successfully
    def get_success_url(self):
        g = Group.objects.get(name='test') # assuming you have a group 'test' created already. check the auth_user_group table in your DB
        g.user_set.add(self.object)
        return reverse('users')  #I have a named url defined below
```

In my **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'list$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='users'), # I have a list view to show a list of existing users
]
```

I tested this in Django 1.8 (I am sure it works in 1.7 as well). I verified the group relationship been created in **auth_user_group** table.

P.S. I have also found this: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-vanilla-views/tree/master which might be useful for your project.