# how to add django groups to a request user dynamically

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I have a model called Employee which has a foreign key field to employee category(like teacher,non-teaching or librarian). I have two groups called 'Library Management' and 'Teacher Management'.

This is my code for Employee model

```
class EmployeeAdmission(User):

    User.username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    User.password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    employee_number =models.CharField(max_length=10)
    joining_date = models.DateField()
    employee_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    employee_middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    employee_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    employee_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER,max_length=20)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    employee_category = models.ForeignKey(AddEmployeeCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='employee')
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Experience_info = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    total_experience = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=YEAR)
```

I made some employee category like teacher and librarian

My logic is based on the category at the time of post request.
say if employee_category is 1. then check for Library Management group and add the group to the request user or if employee_category is 2  then check for Library Management group and add the group to the request user.

this is my code for employee.views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def post(self, request, format=None):
    json = JSONRenderer().render(request.data)
    stream = BytesIO(json)
    data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
    serializer = EmployeeDetailSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():

        category = serializer.fields.get('employee_category',default=None)

        if (category == 1 ):
            library_group = Group.objects.get(name='Library Management')
            request.user.groups.add(library_group)
            request.user.save()

        else :
            teacher_group = Group.objects.get(name='Teacher Management')
            request.user.groups.add(teacher_group)
            request.user.save()

        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have refered these links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288661/adding-a-user-to-a-group-in-django) . 
I am able to save the user but i am still not able to add the groups to the user (Not reflecting on the User model).

Anyone who knows the solution please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am using the exact same code since over a year and it does work. Check on debugger what is happening before and after the add and the save

Comment: Anyway you might consider using a trigger at the model level instead then updating it at every request. We are using something similar with a m2m relation named role and we are using a function to update the users whenever users or roles are updated:
`m2m_changed.connect(update_groups, sender=MISUser.role.through)`
`@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Role.groups.through)`
`def update_all_users(sender, **kwargs):`

Comment: I have tried debugging. When i give the employee_category value to 2. it comes to the Tescher Management group condition check. and the request.user.save() is also getting called. But still doesnt effect.

Comment: did you print request.user.groups at each step? what are their value? Right after the save() put a breakpoint and check the database directly. Is the new group there? Are groups changed in any other part of your application? (search for user.groups in your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer after a lot of research.

When i was using this code.

```
request.user.groups.add(library_group)
request.user.save()
```

the group was getting saved only on the user which has admin not the instance of the "EmployeeAdmission". So to get the instance of the "EmployeeAdmission" I did it like this.

```
employee = serializer.save()
```

after getting the instance of the that model i was able to save it. and it was reflecting in the database.

The code i used was this

```
employee.groups.add(library_group)
employee.save()
```