# Protecting a view without requiring login in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to password protect my registration page in Django without requiring the user to login, but I can't seem to figure it out. My flow should be:

1. User accesses mydomain.com/register/
2. User enters password into `registration_access` form
3. If unsuccessful, user re-enters password
4. If successful, user is presented with `UserCreationForm`
5. If `UserCreationForm` is not filled out properly, user is presented with `UserCreationForm` again + errors
6. If `UserCreationForm` is filled out properly, user is redirected to their profile page

The issue I'm having right now is that I can't redirect a user to a view without a URL (the view containing UserCreationForm).

Here's my code:

`views.py`

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # Gather information from all forms submitted
        user_custom_info = user_information(request.POST)
        user_info = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_info = deejay_form(request.POST)

        # Check to make sure they entered data into each of the forms
        info_validated = user_info.is_valid() and user_custom_info.is_valid() and profile_info.is_valid()

        # If they did...
        if info_validated:

            # Clean the data...
            user_custom_info = user_custom_info.cleaned_data
            user_info = user_info.cleaned_data
            profile_info = profile_info.cleaned_data

            # Create a new user with those traits
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(user_info['username'], user_custom_info['email'], user_info['password1'])
            new_user.first_name = user_custom_info['first_name']
            new_user.last_name = user_custom_info['last_name']
            new_user.save()

            # Create a new deejay with those traits..
            new_deejay = Deejay(user=new_user, dj=profile_info['dj'], role=profile_info['role'], bio=profile_info['bio'], phone=profile_info['phone'])
            new_deejay.save()

            # Log in the user..
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                this_user = authenticate(username=user_info['username'], password=user_info['password1'])
                login(request, this_user)

            # Need to add to group - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288661/adding-a-user-to-a-group-in-django

            # Redirect to dj page
            return redirect('dj_detail', dj_name=Deejay.objects.get(user=request.user).dj)
        else:
            return render(request, 'pages/backend/register.html', {'forms':[user_custom_info, user_info, profile_info]})

    return render(request, 'pages/backend/register.html', {'forms':[user_information, UserCreationForm, deejay_form]})

# View for a password protected registration form
def register_protect(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pw_info = registration_access(request.POST)
        if pw_info.is_valid():
            return redirect(register)
        else:
            return render(request, 'pages/backend/register.html', {'forms':[pw_info]})
    return render(request, 'pages/backend/register.html', {'forms':[registration_access]})
```

`forms.py`

```
class user_information(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class deejay_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deejay
        fields = ('dj', 'role', 'bio', 'phone')

class registration_access(forms.Form):
    secret_password = forms.CharField(label="Secret Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean(self):
        access_password = "mypassword"
        given_password = self.cleaned_data.get('secret_password')
        if given_password != access_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Did you forget your training?")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: what do you mean " that I can't redirect a user to a view without a URL", is that not obvious?

Answer (score 0):

"Redirect" means, by definition, to redirect back to the server. Thus you need to redirect to a URL. You can redirect to the same URL, but then you'd need to write your view to be able to handle the different things you want to do.

To me, it sounds like you'd be better served using Javascript and handle things as a single page app.