# Adding a user to a group using django rest framework programmatically

Tags: django, python-3.6

I want to be able to attach a user to a group upon creation.

Here is the result of select * from auth_group:

[image: image screenshoot]

Here is the my serializer.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta(object):
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'address', 'is_active', 'is_staff',
              'is_superuser', 'date_joined', 'password',)
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Here is my model.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin, UserManager, Group
from django.db import models, transaction

# Create your models here.
from django.utils import timezone


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email,and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    if not extra_fields["group_id"]:
        raise ValueError('User must have group id')
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
            group = Group.objects.get(extra_fields["group_id"])
            group.user_set.add(user)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user
    except:
        raise

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    return self._create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
"""
An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
admin-compliant permissions.

"""
email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone']

def get_full_name(self):
    """" Used to display user's full name """
    return "{}, {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

def __srt__(self):
    return self.email

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return self
```

And finally, here is my view.py:

```
class CreateUserAPIView(APIView):
# Allow any user (authenticated or not) to access this url
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def post(self, request):
    user = request.data
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=user)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response({"user": serializer.data, "status": status.HTTP_200_OK})
```

I want for this request:

```
{
"email": "myemail@gmail.com",
"first_name": "myfirst_name",
"last_name": "mylast_name",
"phone": "000556660",
"address": "myaddress",
"password": "mypassword",
"group_id": 5
}
```

To get this response:

```
{
"status": 200,
user: {
"email": "myemail@gmail.com",
"first_name": "myfirst_name",
"last_name": "mylast_name",
"phone": "000556660",
"address": "myaddress",
"password": "mypassword",
"groups": [5]
}
}
```

I have followed this link [Adding a user to a group in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288661/adding-a-user-to-a-group-in-django) but it's not helping me.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which way is your code not working? What's the behavior when a request is submitted? Any output or error message?

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'address', 'is_active', 'is_staff',
          'is_superuser', 'date_joined', 'password', 'groups')

def create(self, validated_data):
    groups_data = validated_data.pop('groups')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for group_data in groups_data:
        # Group.objects.create(user=user, **group_data)
        user.groups.add(group_data)
    return user
```

Edit:  Because `User` and `Group` are in many-to-many relations so you can directly add the `group` field in the `users` serializers. For more details follow `django.contrib.auth.models` package and `User` inherits `AbstactUser` and `AbstractUser` inherits `PermissionsMixin` which has `groups` as many to many field.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question. Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain how this helps to solve OP's problem? Because he hasn't specified one, so it's a mystery to me how you've managed to come up with a solution.

Comment: So as of my edit, User and Groups are many-to-many fields and now `groups` attribute becomes available to `User` model.