# How to change user of groups? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How to change user of groups? - Django

Hi. When I create a new user. I assign it to some permission groups.
However, as time goes by, some users need to change permissions, so change groups.

I have registered users but in the edition it will be possible to update the user's groups.

How can I just change the groups.

I know it has a function for this, but I don't remember.

Thank you friends.

```
 group = Group.objects.get(id=id)
 group.update(user)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "update the groups"?

Comment: Hi. When I create a new user. I assign it to some permission groups.
However, as time goes by, some users need to change permissions, so change groups. You see?

Comment: I edit the post.

Comment: refer it to understand how to add a user a to a group, and remove the user from the existing group(optional, check with requirements). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288661/adding-a-user-to-a-group-in-django

Comment: I already know how to add. This is done in the user registration. My problem is just changing a user's groups. You see?

Comment: user.groups.add(group)

Comment: Thank you. Adding to a group I already know it is in this format. And to change groups in a user edition, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a user to group,

```
 group = Group.objects.get(id=id)
 group.user_set.add(user)
```

To remove ,

```
group.user_set.remove(user)
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolve with

user_obj.groups.clear()